# Block template tags and include html

Tags: django, django-views

I've got two html files. I want to include one in the other and then use a block statement in the second.

**message.html**

```
<div>
  Hi
</div>

{% block message1 %}

{% endblock message1 %}
```

**main.html**

```
{% include "message.html" %}

{% block message1 %}
     this is a message
{% endblock message1 %}
```

When main.html is rendered, the string "this is a message" doesn't show up. Do you know why?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ***include***, use ***extends***

like this

```
{% extends 'message.html' %}

{% block message1 %}
     this is a message
{% endblock message1 %}
```

You can refer to the official docs about django template tags [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/)